# C# - Verify if Cursor != Default

Tags: c#, cursor

So, I've a problem and I can't resolve it.

When I Click in a Button, the Cursor goes to an determined position, after this, it execute one Click. When it do it, my application is Minimized ( proposital ) and the cursor stay in other program that I use. In this determined position, the cursor change of " Default " to " Hand " and I would like in this moment, my Application Show a Message Box.

The Problem is: when this other program is open, my application don't identify the cursor changed, I use this code:

```
If (Cursor.Current != Cursors.Default)
{ MessageBox.Show("Hello!");
}
```

It not Work.

Why ?
Can help me, please ?

Sorry my bad English XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Cursor.Current`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.current%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property gets the cursor owned by the current thread. That means:

- You can't get your UI's current cursor from a non-UI thread
- You can't get a different process' (and hence a different thread's) cursor

If you want to get the global cursor, you'll need to use a different method. `Cursor.Current` uses [`GetCursor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648388%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) internally. Its documentation states:

> To get information on the global cursor, even if it is not owned by the current thread, use [`GetCursorInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648389(v=vs.85).aspx).

You can P/Invoke this native function using the signatures from [PInvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getcursorinfo).

Here is an example of using it to get the global cursor and convert it to a managed [Cursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instance:

```
CURSORINFO info;
info.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(CURSORINFO));

Boolean ret = GetCursorInfo(out info);

if (!ret) {
    throw new Exception();
}

Cursor c = new Cursor(info.hCursor);
```

Comment: One caveat: It doesn't seem to handle (no pun intended) "custom cursors" very well. I'm reading about it now. It sounds like you're trying to automate an external application. Code injection might be a better method depending on what you're automating.

Comment: Yeah, [`GetIconInfo`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getcursorinfo) seems to be sufficient for identifying custom cursors. Give it a try. Let me know if you need further direction to solve your question.